# Python error immediately after Kivy app runing

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to run a very simple Kivy script:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class SampleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
       return Label(text="Hello world")

SampleKivy().run()
```

but python immediately crashes after the window opens
[image]

I followed instructions for installation on win 10 for Python 3.6.5
I did it with success on an other Windows 10 PC of mine
I also did it with success on an Ubuntu Virtual Machine ( the real true is that the Ubuntu installation was tricky)

Can someone help me solve it please?

Thanks a lot

Kostas

Comment: I don't think you should be returning anything from `build()`? And perhaps add a `def on_pause(self): return True`? See if that helps? You could look through the smaller examples on their website to see how they do it, and what functions are required for a bare minimum. A good example might be the [simple picture viewer](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/examples/gen__demo__pictures__main__py.html)? :)

Comment: This small script ( and others more complicated) worked fine in an other installation on win 10 on a second PC of mine. It worked fine also in Ubuntu. By the way I had no luck with `def on_pause(self): return True?`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the script. Have a look in your `.kivy\logs` directory in your home directory (not `Desktop`). There should a a log file for each time you run a `Kivy` app. Check for any errors posted in the log file.

Comment: Log file seems to me clear enough. Is what I get when I tun the script. This is my log file [link] https://textuploader.com/d3lla

Comment: The log file looks normal. Have you tried clicking on the `Debug` button that appears?

Comment: Grasping at straws here, but I have occasionally seen unexpected behavior if the app is started that way. Try putting `SampleKivy().run()` in an if statement: `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: could you run this script from cmd prompt, and paste the error stack

Comment: Well, it might be the versioning in kivy..remove the version requirement.I remember this fixed it for me once

Comment: I run the script from cmd. I got the same crash screen, No error stack. Log file is the same with https://textuploader.com/d3lla

Comment: I removed kivy version. Got the same crash screen

Comment: I tried the `if __name__ == "__main__":` with no luck

Comment: Yes. `an unhandled win32 exception occurred in python.exe ["error number?"]` The error number changes every time

Answer (score 0):

I restart my PC in safe mode ( for another reason) and problem fixed. 
I can't say that is a solution but it worked for me , for the time

thanks

Kostas